# Modifying a slice of str's

Tags: rust, mutability

I have a `Vec<&str>` and I want to remove a prefix from all of its elements. This is what I vaguely intend:

```
fn remove_prefix(v: &mut [&str], prefix: &str) {
    for t in v.iter_mut() {
        t = t.trim_left_matches(prefix);
    }
}
```

However I can't seem to get all the `mut`'s in the right place. Or maybe it's a lifetime related thing? Can anyone give me a hint? Here is my current error:

```
makefile_to_qbs.rs:22:7: 22:34 error: mismatched types:
 expected `&mut &str`,
    found `&str`
(values differ in mutability) [E0308]
makefile_to_qbs.rs:22           t = t.trim_left_matches(prefix);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`t` is of type `&mut &str`, a mutable pointer to a string slice. You wish to alter what the mutable reference points to, so you need to store a `&str` in `*t`.

```
fn remove_prefix(v: &mut [&str], prefix: &str) {
    for t in v.iter_mut() {
        *t = t.trim_left_matches(prefix);
    }
}
```